# Difference between aligned malloc and standard malloc?

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, malloc, ubuntu-16.04, c11

I'm new to malloc and aligned malloc. I know how to use them. However, I don't know exactly in which case we should use aligned malloc instead of standard malloc. Can you explain it to me please?

Comment: Language? I assume C, but you should also provide other environment details (OS, language implementation, etc). Standard C has only `malloc`, guaranteed to be correctly aligned for all standard data types.

Comment: I use in C11 standard in Ubuntu

Comment: Added those as tags, please confirm and/or change as necessary.

Comment: I have put them as tags, sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`glibc` documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Aligned-Memory-Blocks.html) makes it reasonably clear where you should use `aligned_alloc`:

> The address of a block returned by `malloc` or `realloc` in GNU systems is always a multiple of eight (or sixteen on 64-bit systems). If you need a block whose address is a multiple of a higher power of two than that, use `aligned_alloc` or `posix_memalign`.

The C standard already guarantees that `malloc` will return a suitably aligned memory block for any of the standard types but there may be situations in which you want or need stricter alignment.

As one example, I seem to recall that SSE2 (SIMD) instructions need their data aligned on 16-byte boundaries so you could use `aligned_alloc` to give you that even on systems where `malloc` only guarantees alignment to an 8-byte boundary.