# Why did C++17 introduce std::aligned_alloc?

Tags: c++, malloc, c++17, memory-alignment

**Aim:** To understand the motivation why C++17 introduced [`std::aligned_alloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/aligned_alloc) for dynamic memory management.

**Problem:** For the memory allocation in C++, using `std::malloc` is virtually always discouraged due to various reasons exemplified under [In what cases do I use malloc and/or new?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7970036/3393574). Instead, using `new` expression is almost always encouraged in low-level code (e.g. see [Notes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/malloc)).

Despite this discouragement, I wonder why C++17 introduced `std::aligned_alloc` which looks like a continuation of `std::malloc`.

Is there anything in C++17 (and beyond) that cannot be performed by `new` (or other equivalent utilities encouraged to use, if any)?

**Attempts:** I could only find the following discussion, which is still remotely related to my question:

[Difference between aligned malloc and standard malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677063/difference-between-aligned-malloc-and-standard-malloc)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C++17 bumped up its support for plain C from C99 to C11. It inherited `aligned_alloc` along with other stuff from C11.

paper: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0063r3.html

So the motivation is to make C features available in C++ for those who want them.